# android Window feature problem: the sequence of initializing the feature of window

Tags: android, window

1. requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
2. setContentView(R.layout.main);
3. getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.icon);

The sequence is arbitary, why?

If I put statement 1 and 3 together in a initWindow() method before setContentView, setting left icon has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well most obvious answer is because it written  this way. To be more specific only existing Window implementation for now is [PhoneWindow](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java;h=5592b6d5337e83bd9cb0d94e2a131acfc3a093ec;hb=HEAD) (you can see source with this link) ignores all `setDrawable` calls until content view ( and decor view ) is installed.